# Syscall overhead in Solaris vs Linux

Tags: linux, io, solaris, system-calls

A while ago, I asked a question about the cost of a syscall in Solaris 10 on SPARC hardware. In the past few months, this issue has resurfaced a few times and here is what I found.

If we take a synthetic test where a 300MB file is read from disk in 256-byte blocks, it takes substantially longer in Solaris 10 then it does in Linux. The test is done in the following fashion:

`dd if=test.dat of=/dev/null bs=256`

Even if `test.dat` is stored on a memory-mapped file system like `/tmp`, Linux outperforms Solaris by a big margin. It seems like the overhead of going back and forth between user space and kernel space is substantially higher in Solaris than it is in Linux, even when both run on same hardware.

I have two questions:

1. Is it some kind of a know disadvantage of Solaris over Linux?
2. Is there a way to tune Solaris to match Linux numbers assuming that I cannot increase the size of an I/O block from 256?

Thank you!

Comment: There are a lot of unspecified variables here. Is this on comparable hardware? The same disks? The same filesystems? If you want to answer a question about system call overhead, you should use a different system call that doesn't do other work.

Comment: @alberge The best "comparable hardware" I can get is two instances of a VirtualBox machines running in a Windows7 host. I know that this setup could be flaky but in series of experiments numbers remain within reasonable dispersion. In the test with "/tmp", both file systems are identical - tmpfs. Ihave also enhanced the test by specifying ibs and obs separately and keeping obs at 8192.

Comment: The file systems are only "identical" in that they have the same name. tmpfs implementations share nothing in common between Linux and Solaris. Try to find something that measure system call overhead and not the complex combination you currently use. You should also state the specs of both systems, and find what bottleneck they meet during the test.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've made this a true apples-to-apples comparison whereby the Solaris and LINUX boxes are identical in performance/capacity? Anyways, some key questions to help you through this:

1) If you run the command **vmstat 1** while this **dd** is running, what types of numbers do you get on the Solaris 10 box vs. the LINUX box?

2) What is the elapsed time of that operation? I'm seeing barely 2 seconds on my PC running Solaris 10 x86 to do that...

3) Try using a fully qualified path for your **if** parameter (i.e. **if=/tmp/test.dat** vs **if=test.dat**) just to make doubly sure you are running off of /tmp.

Sean.

Comment: To increase the elapsed time to a better observable value, you can merely increase the size of the input file. On my hardware, a 300MB file is consumed in about 4-5 seconds. I will run vmstat later when I get to the test system. In the meantime, by looking at `prstat` output on Solaris, I did not notice any significant time waiting for I/O. The summation of USR and SYS is close to 100%. And the SCL value is above 0.2M per 1-second sample.

Answer (score 1):

You should include more information in your question. In my opinion, your problem is about file system, it's not about the operation system. XFS allows file systems to be created with block sizes ranging between 512 bytes and 64 kilobytes, allowing the file system to be tuned for the expected use. On Solaris, the default file system is xfs, so 256 bytes block size is not a good parameter, could you please increase it to 512 to see what happen?

Comment: Solaris default files systems are either ufs (S10 and older) or ZFS (S11). For /tmp the default is tmpfs. There is no xfs support on Solaris.